# How can I leverage a pairwise scatter plot to help choose a machine learning model/classifier to distinguish the categories of iris flower?

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-visualization

This is a visualization of the [Iris data](https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/iris) as a pairwise scatter plot.

[image]

The goal is to learn to distinguish three different kinds of iris flower, called setosa, versicolor and virginica.

We can extract following information from the figure above

> it is easy to distinguish setosas (red circles) from the other two classes by just checking if their petal length or width is below some threshold. However, distinguishing versicolor from virginica is slightly harder

Besides this information, is there any other information we can extract to help choose a machine learning model/classifier to distinguish the categories of iris flower?

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do this using a pairs plot. The relation between any number of variables could lie in an arbitrary feature space, which you would not be able to see from such an image.